How to align text within the enumext alternatives?
I wrote a text within the options of a question, I am using the enumext package. I wanted the text I placed to be aligned with the left margin of the document. I used the flushleft function and it didn't work. Is it possible to align the text with the left margin? Below is my code and a photo illustrating my problem.

Here is my code
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}% Margens
\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfigure}              
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}

\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Prof. Ulisses Moreira}
\rhead{Gás ideal}
\cfoot{ - \thepage\hspace{1pt} -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{%
        \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip2pt%
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip-\headrulewidth\vskip-4pt
}}
\makeatother % linha dupla

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{2.2cm}}

\begin{document}    

\thispagestyle{firstpage}


\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{Questões}}
\end{center}

    
\normalsize
    
    
\begin{enumext}[list-indent=0pt,save-ans=test,show-ans=false]

\item Uma certa quantidade de gás ideal ocupa um volume $V_{0}$ quando sua temperatura é $T_{0}$ e sua pressão é $P_{0}$. Expande-se, então, o gás, isotermicamente, até duplicar o seu volume. 

\begin{enumext}[align=left]
    \item Calcule a pressão após a expansão isotérmica. \anskey{$P' = \frac{P}{2}$.}
    
A seguir, mantendo o seu volume constante, sua pressão é restabelecida ao valor original P$_{0}$.

    \item Qual a temperatura final do gás neste último estado de equilíbrio térmico? \anskey{$2T_{0}$.}

\end{enumext}
\end{enumext}
\end{document}


Remember that enumext is a list-based package, so you must set list-indent for the second level in this case, either locally or globally using \setenumext.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}% Margens
\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}

\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Prof. Ulisses Moreira}
\rhead{Gás ideal}
\cfoot{ - \thepage\hspace{1pt} -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{%
        \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip2pt%
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip-\headrulewidth\vskip-4pt
}}
\makeatother % linha dupla

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{2.2cm}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{Questões}}
\end{center}


\normalsize

\setenumext[enumext,2]{align=left,list-indent=0pt}
\begin{enumext}[list-indent=0pt,save-ans=test,show-ans=false]

\item Uma certa quantidade de gás ideal ocupa um volume $V_{0}$ quando 
sua temperatura é $T_{0}$ e sua pressão é $P_{0}$. Expande-se, então, o 
gás, isotermicamente, até duplicar o seu volume.

\begin{enumext}
  \item Calcule a pressão após a expansão isotérmica. \anskey{$P' = \frac{P}{2}$.}
   
  A seguir, mantendo o seu volume constante, sua pressão é restabelecida ao valor original P$_{0}$.
  
  \item Qual a temperatura final do gás neste último estado de equilíbrio térmico? \anskey{$2T_{0}$.}
\end{enumext}
\end{enumext}
\end{document}


Comments (outside the answer):

Don't use tab to format your source code, it will only give you headaches (especially if you use it with the anskey* environment)
You can optimize the execution time by loading only the packages you need (for example inputenc is no longer needed).


Thank you Pablo.
